# EF 6.0 not returning PK key value from Database generated value with Multiple DBcontexts

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a generic repository pattern with unit of work that does the Insert transaction. Due to some specifics, I have a BaseController that gets a company type, and based on that company type I created the ModelEntities ( with a default model that all database-contexts apply to) from the assigned connection string. This generally works, but also causes EF not to return a database generated value. And this is something I definitely need. The model is a Database first generated model.

The value is Identity specified and has an incremental value, so that's not the problem.
I've done a similar thing before and I don't see why it doesn't return.

I hope one of you guys have an answer to this.

I have attached all code below.

BaseController.cs

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public UnitOfWork _unitofwork;
    public BaseController(ModelType.Company company)
    {
        LoadInContext(company);
    }

    public void LoadInContext(ModelType.Company company)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Empty;

        switch (company)
        {
            case ModelType.Company.AT:
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ModelType.Company.ELB:
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ELBEntities"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ModelType.Company.NB:
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NBEntities"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unhandled company");

        }

        _unitofwork = new UnitOfWork(new Entities().CreateEntitiesForDB(connectionString));
    }
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    internal DbContext dbContext;
    public IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        dbContext = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }


    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        T entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entityToDelete)
    {
        if (dbContext.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        dbContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private bool disposed;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        context = dbContext;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Save()
    { }

    public void SaveChangesAsync()
    { }

    public ExampleRepository ExampleRepository
    {
        return new ExampleRepository(context);
    }
}
```

Example repository

```
public class ExampleRepository: Repository<Example>
{
     public ExampleRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
     {}
}
```

Example method

```
public class ExampleController: BaseController
{
    public ExampleController() : base(ModelType.Company.AT)
    {}

    public void ExampleMethod(Example example)
    {
      _unitofwork.ExampleRepository.Insert(example);
       int id = example.Id
       //This does not return the ID.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove all code (methods, interface implements etc.) that is not necessary for your example to run. Please include the code for your `Example` class and your `DbContext` setup.

Comment: Removed the interface references and added exampleRepository.
The content within Example class doesn't matter since its generated content just try  int ID {get;set;} ,
my dbcontext setup has been provided as I said, DB first through an .edmx file imgur.com/a/D6rmeaJ

Comment: Your question is more readable if you removed trash methods like `Get(...)`, `GetAll()` etc.. The question would be much easier to answer if you only incuded the minimal needed to reproduce your error. We're missing the key elements of your question, when you do not include everything. Have you added the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the `Example.ID` property?

Comment: Since it's generated code ( db first model), this is done by the .edmx file automatically as shown through the screenshot.
Removed unnecessary methods

Comment: You can shorten down your code much more. How you find your connection string, how you dispose things are irrelevant code. I'm unable to make your code work, since there is missing a lot... Try to make a new project and reproduce your problem with as little code as possible, and update your question with this code. Try to do everything in the same class, and just hardcode things like your connection string...

Comment: I've done similar code like this before, and that one worked fine. Hence I did not attach a sample project but the way it was coded. I'll get a sample project running with a sql script to replicate the issue.

Comment: Could not replicate the issue with a sample project like I said I would. Will look at more details in the string,model and such. Thanks for your help, this clarified something at least.

Comment: Here is the sample project that does work.. https://mega.nz/#!GAhiEY4B!Oi6cc7G_IpXlgMBPj51nHl_P-bY1O0zmM81Yq5YdEZk

Still having the issue with my project however. It looks like the context entity doesn't get updated after a savingChanges, even though it transacts the entity to the database. It's about a second faster than my empty example return that has Id with it.

Comment: How are you configuring the entities? EntityTypeConfiguration, ModelBuilder, or attributes? Is `ModelType.Company.AT.Id` set up as with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity?`

Comment: Entities are configured as a DB first model.
ModelType is a specified enum attached to a table within the database.
The ID I want generated does not return in the dbcontext, in my sample project I'm unable to replicate this. The design of the table it's about is pretty old but I've followed all the standards. I still can't find out how this happens, but when I have a chance to refactor the whole model, I'll fix this. For now I fixed it dirty ( read, regetting the last insert through EF and attaching that entity to the rest of the process)